# get style.width when property set with className

Tags: javascript

How can you get the property style.width if it is set with className?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a node's *computed* width, which is its physical width after all styles are applied.

See [here](http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/dom-width-height.php) for how.

As you can see, `elementNode.offsetWidth` appears to be the most portable.

Comment: It seems like the link is broken...!