# How to get css width of class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My question is, how can i get width parameter of class css style?
For example i have `<div class="page css-1" id="page1">` div with id=page and classes "page" and "css-1". I want to get width parameter of **css-1** class style?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get style.width when property set with className](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770140/get-style-width-when-property-set-with-classname)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to ignore that `<div>`, create a new one with the class you care about and check its style attributes. You need to add it to the DOM for it to adopt the CSS of the document.

```
var div = $('<div>').addClass('css-1').hide();
$('body').append(div);
var width = div.css('width');
div.remove();
```